# How to find how many nodes are connecting to Geth?

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, peers

I've lunched a Geth server with default `maxpeers` which is 100 regarding to original documents. Now, I need to know how many nodes are connecting to my node? Is there any command to find it in Geth console?

Comment: @Ismael, alberto's answer was enough for my question. I needed it regarding to my previous question that you had answered it at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82947/can-we-improve-the-performance-of-geth-server-by-setting-maxpeers-to-0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check the numbers of peers connected you can use the following command with the Geth console:

```
> net.peerCount
11
```

And if you want to get more information about the connected peers, you can use the command:

```
> admin.peers
[{
    caps: ["eth/61", "eth/62", "eth/63"],
    id: "08a6b39263470c78d3e4f58e3c997cd2e7af623afce64656cfc56480babcea7a9138f3d09d7b9879344c2d2e457679e3655d4b56eaff5fd4fd7f147bdb045124",
    name: "Geth/v1.5.0-unstable/linux/go1.5.1",
    network: {
      localAddress: "192.168.0.104:51068",
      remoteAddress: "71.62.31.72:30303"
    },
    protocols: {
      eth: {
        difficulty: 17334052235346465000,
        head: "5794b768dae6c6ee5366e6ca7662bdff2882576e09609bf778633e470e0e7852",
        version: 63
      }
    }
}, /* ... */ {
```

For more information, check the [documentation](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/interface/peer-to-peer).