# GETH node maxpeers performance and benefit

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to optimize my node for transaction propagation speed.

Expanding on this question:

[Can we improve the performance of Geth server by setting maxpeers to 0?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/82947/can-we-improve-the-performance-of-geth-server-by-setting-maxpeers-to-0)

Are there any data available regarding transactions propagation speed and number of peers?  I've read a number of times to use "reasonable" amount of peers.  What is "reasonable"?

Thanks

Comment: node should be working faster with bigger maxpeers numbers